# Simplest way to generate graphs using javascript and json

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, graph

What's the simplest way to generate graphs from values coming from an api using javascript and boostrap? My endpoint output is like this:

```
[
  {
    "battery": "22.7",
    "temperature": "80",
    "speed": "77",
    "time": "2016-02-12 14:09:04"
  },
  {
    "battery": "22.8",
    "temperature": "82",
    "speed": "99",
    "time": "2016-02-12 14:09:04"
  },
  {
    "battery": "22.7",
    "temperature": "80",
    "speed": "77",
    "time": "2016-02-12 14:08:22"
  }
]
```

Comment: bootstrap is not a graphing library.

Answer (score 0):

I used this Jquery plugin ages ago.

http://canvasjs.com/jquery-charts/